# Mule Server 3.6 > Anypoint Studio > CloudHub > 405 Not Allowed

Tags: mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

I am encountering the error when trying out my app. It works fine on my local instance as well as on a stand-alone Mule Server, but not on CloudHub. Any reason why this problem occurs?

*Update*
The app doesn't have any issues running from Studio on my local machine. The problem only occurred after I deployed it to CloudHub. I am not able to access the app from CloudHub and encounter a 405 Not Allowed (nginx) error page.

CloudHub logs shows the app has started successfully as far as I understand it. See the CloudHub deployment logs below:

```
19:29:02.272 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Deploying application to 1 workers.
19:29:05.450 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Provisioning CloudHub worker...
19:29:07.277 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Deploying application to 1 workers.
19:29:08.325 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Provisioning CloudHub worker...
19:29:25.696 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Starting CloudHub worker at 52.74.74.41 ...
19:29:32.862 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Starting CloudHub worker at 54.169.12.90 ...
19:30:49.027 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Worker(54.169.12.90): Starting your application...
19:30:50.715 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'myapp'                                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
19:30:50.958 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Monitoring enabled: true
19:30:50.958 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Registering ping flow injector...
19:30:50.975 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Creating the PersistentQueueManager. Asynchronous VM queues will be persistent.
19:30:50.984 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | About to create the PersistentQueueManager with environment: scope: 55824160e4b0f5ecab93e207_559f73dfe4b02b744ec0f626 bucket: ch-persistent-queues-us-east-prod accessKey: AKIAIYBZZZI7M2PAT4WQ region: ap-southeast-1 privateKey: no
19:30:53.393 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Apply ap-southeast-1 to the client com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient@5c6c69b6
19:30:53.393 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | New sqsClient is created com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient@5c6c69b6
19:30:53.412 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Apply ap-southeast-1 to the client com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client@4a1e0237
19:30:53.469 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | New s3Client is created com.mulesoft.ch.queue.sqs.clients.S3Client@20d271f6
19:30:53.470 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Done with SQSQueueManagementService() instance
19:30:53.505 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising RegistryBroker
19:30:53.760 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@44b5763: startup date [Fri Jul 10 11:30:53 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
19:30:57.438 | 07/10/2015 | WARN | Schema warning: Use of element <response-builder> is deprecated.  HTTP transport is deprecated and will be removed in Mule 4.0. Use HTTP module instead..
19:30:57.630 | 07/10/2015 | WARN | Schema warning: Use of element <header> is deprecated.  HTTP transport is deprecated and will be removed in Mule 4.0. Use HTTP module instead..
19:30:58.537 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Using files for tx logs /opt/mule/mule-3.6.2-R43/./.mule/myapp/queue-tx-log/tx1.log and /opt/mule/mule-3.6.2-R43/./.mule/myapp/queue-tx-log/tx2.log
19:30:58.538 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Using files for tx logs /opt/mule/mule-3.6.2-R43/./.mule/myapp/queue-xa-tx-log/tx1.log and /opt/mule/mule-3.6.2-R43/./.mule/myapp/queue-xa-tx-log/tx2.log
19:30:58.632 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
19:30:59.749 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising flow: myappFlow
19:30:59.749 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@4fe27195
19:30:59.856 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising service: myappFlow.stage1
19:31:00.389 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Registering  the queue=55824160e4b0f5ecab93e207_559f73dfe4b02b744ec0f626_2D1531125C052F65252D3BF0500990 with display name=seda.queue(myappFlow.stage1)
19:31:00.402 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='/opt/mule/mule-3.6.2-R43/apps/myapp/myapp.xml'}]"
19:31:00.403 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='/opt/mule/mule-3.6.2-R43/apps/myapp/myapp.xml'}]"
19:31:00.430 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Apply ap-southeast-1 to the client com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient@1c5e47e5
19:31:00.430 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | New sqsClient is created com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient@1c5e47e5
19:31:00.448 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Apply ap-southeast-1 to the client com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client@7b8419b2
19:31:00.468 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | New s3Client is created com.mulesoft.ch.queue.sqs.clients.S3Client@2c611f62
19:31:00.473 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Done with SQSQueueManagementService() instance
19:31:00.504 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Starting app 'myapp'                                     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
19:31:00.561 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting ResourceManager
19:31:00.561 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting persistent queue manager
19:31:00.562 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Started ResourceManager
19:31:00.574 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Successfully opened CloudHub ObjectStore
19:31:00.590 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ DevKit Extensions (0) used in this application                               +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
19:31:00.591 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting model: _muleSystemModel
19:31:00.594 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting flow: myappFlow
19:31:00.595 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting service: myappFlow.stage1
19:31:00.881 | 07/10/2015 | WARN | HTTP transport is deprecated and will be removed in Mule 4.0. Use HTTP module instead.
19:31:00.947 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising connector: connector.http.mule.default
19:31:01.156 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | No suitable connector in application, new one is created and used.
19:31:01.158 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Connected: HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=5f68f6a9
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
19:31:01.158 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting: HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=5f68f6a9
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
19:31:01.159 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting connector: connector.http.mule.default
19:31:01.169 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising flow: ____ping____flow_____76326334
19:31:01.169 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@66551924
19:31:01.186 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising service: ____ping____flow_____76326334.stage1
19:31:01.380 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting flow: ____ping____flow_____76326334
19:31:01.381 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting service: ____ping____flow_____76326334.stage1
19:31:01.387 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Registering listener: ____ping____flow_____76326334 on endpointUri: http://localhost:7557/____ping____
19:31:01.459 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
19:31:01.542 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Initialising: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
19:31:01.559 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Connecting clusterizable message receiver
19:31:01.563 | 07/10/2015 | WARN | Localhost is being bound to all local interfaces as specified by the "mule.tcp.bindlocalhosttoalllocalinterfaces" system property. This property may be removed in a future version of Mule.
19:31:01.575 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting clusterizable message receiver
19:31:01.575 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Starting: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
19:31:01.644 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Listening for requests on http://localhost:8085
19:31:01.645 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Mule is embedded in a container already launched by a wrapper.Duplicates will not be registered. Use the org.tanukisoftware.wrapper:type=WrapperManager MBean instead for control.
19:31:01.675 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Attempting to register service with name: Mule.myapp:type=Endpoint,service="____ping____flow_____76326334",connector=connector.http.mule.default,name="endpoint.http.localhost.7557.ping"
19:31:01.676 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Registered Endpoint Service with name: Mule.myapp:type=Endpoint,service="____ping____flow_____76326334",connector=connector.http.mule.default,name="endpoint.http.localhost.7557.ping"
19:31:01.686 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Registered Connector Service with name Mule.myapp:type=Connector,name="connector.http.mule.default.1"
19:31:01.689 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | 
**********************************************************************
* Application: myapp                                                 *
* OS encoding: /, Mule encoding: UTF-8                               *
*                                                                    *
* Agents Running:                                                    *
*   DevKit Extension Information                                     *
*   Batch module default engine                                      *
*   Clustering Agent                                                 *
*   JMX Agent                                                        *
**********************************************************************
19:31:01.754 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Registering  the queue=55824160e4b0f5ecab93e207_559f73dfe4b02b744ec0f626_515E160FC244EB5157E8E7C8B162E0 with display name=seda.queue(____ping____flow_____76326334.stage1)
19:31:02.561 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Worker(54.169.12.90): Your application has started successfully.
19:31:09.295 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Mule system health monitoring started for your application.
19:31:59.537 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Worker(52.74.74.41): Starting your application...
19:32:01.200 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'myapp'                                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
19:32:01.525 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Creating the PersistentQueueManager. Asynchronous VM queues will be persistent.
19:32:01.526 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | About to create the PersistentQueueManager with environment: scope: 55824160e4b0f5ecab93e207_559f73dfe4b02b744ec0f626 bucket: ch-persistent-queues-us-east-prod accessKey: AKIAIYBZZZI7M2PAT4WQ region: ap-southeast-1 privateKey: no
19:32:07.054 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Stopping app 'myapp'                                     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
19:32:07.056 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Stopping flow: ____ping____flow_____807729792
19:32:07.056 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Removing listener on endpointUri: http://localhost:7557/____ping____
19:32:07.057 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Stopping: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
19:32:07.059 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Disposing: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
19:32:07.059 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Stopping service: ____ping____flow_____807729792.stage1
19:32:12.028 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Worker(52.74.74.41): Your application has started successfully.
19:32:15.041 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Mule system health monitoring started for your application.
19:32:33.488 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Stopping flow: myappFlow
19:32:33.489 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Stopping service: myappFlow.stage1
19:32:37.061 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Application was updated successfully with zero downtime. The new version of your application has been launched and the old version has been stopped.
19:32:37.545 | 07/10/2015 | SYSTEM | Your application is started.
```

Comment: What *exactly* is it that doesn't work in CloudHub? Your question is to vague to be answered as is.

Comment: @DavidDossot Sorry, I forgot to add details... I encounter that error when I send POST data via Google Chrome's Postman. Please see this screenshot http://goo.gl/VKbUxB

Comment: This is not a way to ask a question, you need to provide your Mule config that you have tried as well as your exception details more .. putting a screenshots without any further details will not help to solve your issue

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary, sorry I'm new to Mule. May I ask what Mule config you need and where can I find it? I believe I haven't implemented any exception handling.

Comment: In Studio, you have the `Message Flow` view and the `Configuration XML` one that show as tabs on the canvas. The configuration is what's in the `Configuration XML` one, which matches the `.xml` file that's packaged for your app and deployed. The exceptions are whatever it is you are seeing in the logs when that error occurs. Sharing all that will help us see what the possible problems are.

Comment: @afelisatti, The app doesn't have any issues running from Studio on my local machine. The problem only occurred after I deployed it to CloudHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. From the deployment logs:

```
19:31:01.644 | 07/10/2015 | INFO | Listening for requests on http://localhost:8085
```

The host should have been the default **All interfaces [0.0.0.0]**, and the port *8085* is not allowed on CloudHub. And I must use the default port **8081**.

I was running multiple Mule apps on my local machine at the same time, that's why I had used a different port for this app, and I wasn't aware that port 8085 is not allowed on CloudHub.

Thank you all for the response.

Answer (score 0):

for the port please try using ${http.port} or ${https.port} as per your requirement when deployed to Cloud hub.
It worked for me.

Comment: is that a standard property? Or, do I still have to specify the values for those on my Environment Variables?